# Python Text processing (str.contains)

Tags: python, string, pandas, contains

I am using str.contains for text analytics in Pandas. If for the sentence "My latest Data job was an Analyst" , I want a combination of the words "Data" & "Analyst" but at the same time I want to specify the number of words between the two words used for the combination( here it is 2 words between "Data" and "Analyst".Currently I am using (DataFile.XXX.str.contains('job') &  DataFile.XXX.str.contains('Analyst') to get the counts for "job Analyst". 
How can I Specify the number of words in between the 2 words in the str.contains syntax.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please share a sample of your DataFrame. Pandas can be really useful library but it is not meant for everything.  Text analytics... maybe.. depends.. most likely not. And please, before asking more questions take 30 min to read this: [ask].

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Unfortunately this isn't a discussion forum or tutorial service. Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links on that page.

Comment: I know how to answer this question. But I'm not going to, because your question does not meet the standards of this site. Please provide a [mcve] and also read [ask]..

Answer (score 0):

You can't. At least, not in a simple or standardized way.

Even the basics, like how you define a "word," are a *lot* more complex than you probably imagine. Both word parsing and lexical proximity (e.g. "are two words within distance D of one another in sentence s?") is the realm of [natural language processing (NLP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing). NLP and proximity searches are not part of basic Pandas, nor of Python's standard string processing. You could import something like [NLTK, the Natural Language Toolkit](http://www.nltk.org/) to solve this problem in a general way, but that's a whole 'nother story.

Let's look at a simple approach. First you need a way to parse a string into words. The following is rough by NLP standards, but will work for simpler cases:

```py
def parse_words(s):
    """
    Simple parser to grab English words from string.
    CAUTION: A simplistic solution to a hard problem. 
             Many possibly-important edge- and corner-cases 
             not handled. Just one example: Hyphenated words.
    """
    return re.findall(r"\w+(?:'[st])?", s, re.I)
```

E.g.:

```py
>>> parse_words("and don't think this day's last moment won't come ")
['and', "don't", 'think', 'this', "day's", 'last', 'moment', "won't", 'come']
```

Then you need a way to find all the indices in a list where a target word is found:

```py
def list_indices(target, seq):
    """
    Return all indices in seq at which the target is found.
    """
    indices = []
    cursor = 0
    while True:
        try:
            index = seq.index(target, cursor)
        except ValueError:
            return indices
        else:
            indices.append(index)
            cursor = index + 1
```

And finally a decision making wrapper:

```py
def words_within(target_words, s, max_distance, case_insensitive=True):
    """
    Determine if the two target words are within max_distance positiones of one
    another in the string s.
    """
    if len(target_words) != 2:
        raise ValueError('must provide 2 target words')

    # fold case for case insensitivity
    if case_insensitive:
        s = s.casefold()
        target_words = [tw.casefold() for tw in target_words]
        # for Python 2, replace `casefold` with `lower`

    # parse words and establish their logical positions in the string
    words = parse_words(s)
    target_indices = [list_indices(t, words) for t in target_words]

    # words not present
    if not target_indices[0] or not target_indices[1]:
        return False

    # compute all combinations of distance for the two words
    # (there may be more than one occurance of a word in s)
    actual_distances = [i2 - i1 for i2 in target_indices[1] for i1 in target_indices[0]]

    # answer whether the minimum observed distance is <= our specified threshold
    return min(actual_distances) <= max_distance
```

So then:

```py
>>> s = "and don't think this day's last moment won't come at last"
>>> words_within(["THIS", 'last'], s, 2)
True

>>> words_within(["think", 'moment'], s, 2)
False
```

The only thing left to do is map that back to Pandas:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'desc': [
    'My latest Data job was an Analyst',
    'some day my prince will come',
    'Oh, somewhere over the rainbow bluebirds fly',
    "Won't you share a common disaster?",
    'job! rainbow! analyst.'
]})

df['ja2'] = df.desc.apply(lambda x: words_within(["job", 'analyst'], x, 2))
df['ja3'] = df.desc.apply(lambda x: words_within(["job", 'analyst'], x, 3))
```

[image]

This is basically how you'd solve the problem. Keep in mind, it's a rough and simplistic solution. Some simply-posed questions are not simply-answered. NLP questions are often among them.